# Time of day first traffic light exploded

Tags: technology

The first traffic light was installed in December 1868 at Bridge Street, Great George Street and Parliament Street in London. It exploded on 2 January 1869. What time of day did it explode?

Comment: I presume you mean 1868, not 1968. (It might also be useful to know why you're asking.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[According to a BBC article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/nottingham/content/articles/2009/07/16/john_peake_knight_traffic_lights_feature.shtml), the traffic lights exploded sometime in the evening:

> But a month into the project disaster struck. **One evening** a leaky gas mains resulted in one of the traffic lights exploding in the face of the policeman who was operating them. He was badly burnt.
>
> The project, so enthusiastically greeted, was immediately dropped.

Comment: That is useful, but I have already found it. Unfortunately, I am looking for the exact time. I expect it to be between 7pm and 9:30pm, although that is based on a conversation I had some time ago on the subject, so I can't be sure I remember it correctly.

Comment: @Deathkill14 If you already found it, add it to your question and also specify exactly what you are looking for. Why am I spending time trying to find out something you already know?

Comment: Fair point. My apologies. Time of day was not specific enough. I should have said exact time.